# How do I disable error reporting to Canonical, but keep Apport enabled?

Tags: apport, privacy

I disabled error reporting in **Privacy Settings**, however apport still connects to **people.canonical.com** and sends crash dumps. It even asks, if I want to include configuration files, which I have edited.

Comment: Keep apport enabled to send what to who ? I would suggest you disable apport and re-enable it if you wish to send a bug report period.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen But I want to get notified if something crashes in background.